# Java reorganizable grid

Tags: java, user-interface

Is there any layout or library in Java to make GUIs that contain a list of data with separate items, and the rows can be reordered by clicking the top of the column. I'm sure that was a terrible job of explaining what I want, so here is a screenshot showing what I mean:

[image]

(taken from Spotify's desktop client, but you can find GUIs like this in all kinds of apps.)

Comment: See the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)?

Your criteria:

- **A list of data** – yes. A table model can be as simple as an `Object[][]` or as complex as a custom class.
- **Reordering by clicking header** – yes. You can use a [`TableRowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) to sort when the column header is clicked.

For information on tables, see the **["How to Use Tables" section of *The Java Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)**.

This document also has **[a section, "Sorting and Filtering"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)**, that talks about sorting with the column header. Here's an excerpt:

> Table sorting and filtering is managed by a sorter object. The easiest
>   way to provide a sorter object is to set autoCreateRowSorter bound
>   property to true:
>
> ```
> JTable table = new JTable();
> table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
> ```
>
> This action defines a row sorter that is an instance of
>   `javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter`. This provides a table that does a
>   simple locale-specific sort when the user clicks on a column header.
>   This is demonstrated in [`TableSortDemo.java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableSortDemoProject/src/components/TableSortDemo.java), as seen in this screen
>   shot:
>
> [image: TableSortDemo]

More reference:

- [`JTable` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)
- [`TableRowSorter` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html)